# Unable to add test results to some testcases, in Rally

Tags: java, rally, testcase

Recently, When I try to add results to some testcases (from rally web page), I see the following error.

"The Test Case Result 2013-02-28 Pass could not be saved.
Please correct the errors identified below and click one of the "Save" buttons."

I already have some results already added to those testcases but now I can't add any result anymore. I don't think I am doing anything wrong, because if i try the same process with other testcases I can add results to them without any problem.

Also, if I use java application to add results to those testcases, the application throws a Nullpointer exception.

Anyone got any idea about this...?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like something's not quite right. Please file a case with Rally Support (rallysupport@rallydev.com) - we can look into this with Rally's Devs and Ops team to help find out what's wrong.